# Составление строкового литерала с помощью макросов

Tags: c++, строки, макросы, строковый-литерал

Почему этот пример не работает (не составляет строку с символом `A`)? Как получить ожидаемое поведение? Необходимо для конфигурации строк в зависимости от ОС, т.е. на одной ОС `CHAR` будет одним, на другой - другим.

```
#define CHAR "41"

int main() {
    constexpr auto x = "\u00" CHAR;
}
```

> error: incomplete universal character name \u00

Comment: `x  = "\\u00" CHAR;` Насчет ОС надо использовать соответствующие макросы https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580211/4711135

Comment: @AlexanderChernin тогда он составляет строку `"\u0041"` вместо желаемой `"A"`

Comment: Убирайте `"\u00"` и делайте `#define CHAR "A" `

Comment: @user7860670 мне нужна именно конкатенация, т.к. могут быть разные префиксы и коды, например `"\U000000"` ещё

Comment: Тогда делайте `#define CHAR "\U0000..."` сразу. А вообще в обычной строке из `char` не должно быть символов юникода.

Comment: @user7860670 почему не должно? кодировка файла позволяет

Comment: Потому что char не может содержать символов юникода, а все стандартные функции, работающие со строками из char, не предполагают обработку многобайтовых последовательностей.

Comment: @user7860670 я в UTF-8 всё храню согласно https://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: Ну вот не делайте так. Надо разграничивать область применения UTF-8, и четко представлять, что UTF-8 обратно совместим со обычными однобайтовыми строками с ASCII символами, но не наоборот.

Comment: @user7860670 согласно нему я не использую для определения длины стандартные функции и тому подобное, тогда в чём проблема и почему не делать?

Comment: По-хорошему для UTF-8 последовательностей в С++20 ввели отдельный тип `char8_t`. Хотя в целом поддержка UTF-8 в стандартном С++ не особо улучшилась. А если программа предполагает обработку строк с юникодом (т.е. не просто статические строки или литералы), то тогда стоит сразу использовать ICU.

Comment: @user7860670 у меня все файлы в UTF-8 хранятся, чем лучше использование `u8"..."` вместо `"..."` для строковых литералов?

Comment: Меньше риска передать их функцию, не ожидающую мультибайтовый `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define STRINGIZE(str) #str
#define TO_LITERAL_(_char_)   STRINGIZE( \u00 ##  _char_ )
#define TO_LITERAL(_char_)   TO_LITERAL_(_char_)

#define CHAR 41

auto constexpr A = "foo-" TO_LITERAL(CHAR) "-bar";
```

Но, это будет работать только если CHAR две цифры. Нужно не забыть ведущий ноль, а белее дву-байтные последовательности должны использовать отдельный макрос...
Возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону формирования нужных строк в run-time:

```
const std::string CHAR(1, 41);
auto const A = "foo-" + CHAR + "-bar";
```

Comment: Это не будет работать по причинам, изложенным в соседнем ответе.

Comment: а потом это пойдет в прод, случайно станет успешным и один день превратится в новый log4j

Answer (score 2):

А оно так не работает. Сущность вида \uXXXX называется [universal character name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Теперь читаем https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases и видим 4 стадию (фазу?) трансляции, где описан Ваш случай

> The preprocessor is executed. If a universal character name is formed by token concatenation, the behavior is undefined.

Если такой токен был сформирован в результате конкатенации, то поведение не определено.

Что же делать? тут нужно смотреть глубже в Ваш код. Но в любом случае Ваша конструкция вызывает одни вопросы. В целом, неверно Вам нужно просто полноценно сделать два объявления или просто посмотреть, как сделан TCHAR  в студии.

Comment: смысл в том, что я 1 раз определю CHAR = 41 для одной ОС, а далее во множестве строк с разными префиксами могу подставить этот CHAR

Comment: А с таким подходом надо делать `CHAR_WITH_U_PREFIX`, `CHAR_WITH_X_PREFIX` и т.п.

Comment: а у Вас CHAR будет всегда меньше 128?

Comment: нет, не всегда.

Comment: просто если CHAR больше 127, то там не все так просто. И обычная конкатенация уже не подойдет.

Answer (score -1):

> Необходимо для конфигурации строк в зависимости от ОС, т.е. на одной
> ОС CHAR будет одним, на другой - другим.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #define CHAR '\u0041'
#elif _WIN64
    #define CHAR '\u00..'
...
#else
    #define CHAR '\u00..'
#endif

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << CHAR; // Под Windows (_WIN32) выводит "A"
}
```

Comment: смысл в том, что я 1 раз определю `CHAR` = 41 для одной ОС, а далее во множестве строк с разными префиксами могу подставить этот `CHAR`

Comment: Символ с кодом 41 везде остается таким.

Comment: @user7860670 это понятно, я думал, в конечном итоге, ему нужны разные символы для разных ОС

Comment: @AlexanderChernin да, на другой ОС другие. Тут проблема в одиночных кавычках